# Write Optimization in SwiftUI updating EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

I have an array inside my EnvironmentObject that drives a few of my views. Now I need an update function for that array. Some elements might change, some may not.

Should I first check each element whether it "needs" the update and only write to the array if it does or am I overthinking it because Swift / SwiftUI will optimize out write operations that won't actually change data?

Here is an example:

```
func newValue(forIndex index: Int) -> Double {
    if index % 5 == 0 {
        return Double(index) + 0.5
    }else {
        return Double(index)
    }
}
var array = Array(stride(from: 0.0, to: 1_000_000.0, by: 1))
for i in 0..<array.count {
    let new = newValue(forIndex: i)
    if new != array[i] {
        array[i] = new
    }
}
```

Or this...

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    array[i] = newValue(forIndex: i)
}
```

**Clarification added:**
I am trying to avoid unnecessary data writes and UIupdates. I mean if one array element already is at 2.0 I don’t want to “change” it to 2.0 by setting it to 2.0 again and I certainly don’t want to cause a redraw in this case.
Do I have to do this avoidance check myself or is Swift already doing it for me by optimization?

Comment: Yes, If your array type is stored within an ObservableObject class and is marked Published SwiftUI will handle updating views for you.  You just need to make sure you are using the correct (at) environment handlers (ie. ObservedObject, & Published)